# how to modify the real or imaginary part of a complex number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am not used to Complex class in Ruby. I read the [doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Complex.html) but I cannot figure how to modify the real or imaginary part of such a complex number. The accessor to modify these fields is not provided.

c=Complex(1,2)
c.real= 4 # impossible as is

So my question is : how to modify  the real or imaginary part of a complex number in Ruby ?

I particulary think a solution based on open class should be possible ?

Comment: You can always create a new complex number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a new complex number:

```
c = Complex(1, 2)
c = Complex(2, c.imag)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c = Complex(4, c.imaginary)
```

If you do a

```
c.methods - 1.methods  # => [:marshal_dump, :marshal_load]
```

You can see what methods a complex number has which a normal integer doesn't.  Those are the only two, and they clearly won't let you set the real part, which means you simply can't do it aside from just creating a new one.  You can of course change the number by doing arithmetic operations on it, but if you want to explicitly set the real part, re-assigning the variable is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify the number, but you can create new one based on it and assign result to the same variable:

```
c = Complex(1, 2)
c = Complex(4, c.imaginary)
c            # => (4+2i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example :

```
c = Complex(2, 3)
# incrementing the real part:
c + 2
=> (4+3i)

# incrementing the imaginary part:
c + Complex(0,2)
=> (2, 5i)
```